Svelte 5 snippets parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type
After upgrading to Svelte 5, I tried the new {#snippet ...}. I am getting this type errors, but in the svelte docs it is like they do not exist for them.
{#snippet NavLink(href, text)}
    <a class="text-white" {href}>{text}</a>
{/snippet}

Parameter href implicitly has an any type.
We can fix this issue provisionally by doing this (but I don't like it):
{#snippet NavLink(/** @type {any} */ href)}
    <a class="text-white" {href}>hello</a>
{/snippet}

Is there a better way?

I think you mean Svelte 5, not SvelteKit 5

You probably have checkJs enabled in your TypeScript config.
There are various options:

Disable the option if you don't mind JS and things like Snippet parameters not being type checked.
Disable the strict/noImplicitAny option.
Use <script lang="ts"> in the component to allow TS syntax, then you can type the snippet parameters more easily:
{#snippet NavLink(href: string, text: string)}
    <a class="text-white" {href}>{text}</a>
{/snippet}



